# Difference in ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle and DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle

Tags: wpf, windowsformshost

Can someone please let me know the difference between code :

1.

```
 System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += (s, e) => System.Windows.Forms.Application.RaiseIdle(EventArgs.Empty);
```

And 
2.

```
 DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
 timer.Tick += (s, e) => System.Windows.Forms.Application.RaiseIdle(EventArgs.Empty);
 timer.Start();
```

We are hosting WinFrom UserControl in WPF app using `WindowsFormsHost`.
We are trying to load images(around 1000) on dispatcher thread and also when application goes idle we are updating some menus and UI in Winform contorl using Application.Idle event of WinForm. 
Things are working fine in first case but it does not work in 2nd case. In second case I need to move mouse to continue loading images other wise image loading stops. 
I am going to use the first one becuase I need to fix the bug. 
But I need to understand the difference before pushing the code.

Comment: This is DoEvents() code with a different name.  With all the problems associated with that method, like having no idea exactly when code runs and why it crashes your program.  Ultimately this is an XY question, completely unclear why you are not using a thread or async/await.

Comment: Modifying the Winform control is not an option. Application.Idle event has to be supported because Winfrom control needs this to make UI updates.